# How to prevent overlapping opacity of text in CSS?

Tags: html, css

There are two semi-transparent text characters that overlap. The characters are contained within the same tag.

```
<p>┻━</p>
```

```
p {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

In the area where these two characters overlap, their opacity adds up.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent "double opacity" when characters overlap?

Comment: Basically, no there isn't

Comment: But maybe you can play with `letter-spacing` css property to avoid overlapping

Comment: Is it possible to use a different (mono spaced programming) font that handles spacing slightly differently?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a slight rotation

```
(transform: rotate(0.01deg))
```

hides the double opacity overlap.